# Customize "Reset Page Content" confirm message?

Tags: web-part, personalization

The user sees this message when they "Reset Page Content":

> You are about to reset all personalized Web Parts to their shared
>   values and delete any private Web Parts. Click OK to complete this
>   operation. Click Cancel to keep your personalized Web Part settings
>   and private Web Parts.

How can I customize this?

Ideally via Javascript, but I'll take a server-side customization if that's necessary.

Comment: Did you see my answer? :) I've created a fully working code and wonder if it reaches your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a content editor webpart to page with the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ReplaceText()
{
    MSOStrings.ResetPagePersonalizationDialogText = 'Custom Message';
}

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('ReplaceText');
</script>
```